# Definition of stalks of etale sheaves.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, etale-cohomology

Let $\bar{x} \longmapsto X$ be a geometric point of a scheme. Let $G$ be a sheaf on $X_{et}$. Then there are two definitions of the stalks:
$G_{\bar{x}} = i^{*}G(\bar{x}) $ and $\varinjlim_{U,i_{u}}G(U)$, where $(U,i_{u})$ is an etale neighborhood of $\bar{x}$. How do these two definitions coincide? The problem is that in case of $i^{*}G(\bar{x})$ we need to also sheafify.

Comment: Hint: What is the etale site of a separably closed field?

Comment: Finite copies of itself? But is the morphism on each copy the identity or some non-trivial automorphism of the field?

Comment: @PavlePapunashvili Yes finite copies of itself, and no there are no non-trivial automorphisms involved here. The category of sheaves on $k^{sep}$ is equivalent to the category of abelian group via the functor $\mathcal{F}\mapsto\mathcal{F}(k^{sep})$.